# Trouble when building iOS app using "bundle exec Fastlane beta"

Tags: ios, react-native, bundle, fastlane

I'm trying to build & upload to Apple Developer an iOS app built with react-native.

Here is the command I'm executing :

```
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

And here is the error I'm getting during the 'build app' step :

```
[15:57:22]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace mobile.xcworkspace -scheme mobile -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-01-24/myapp\ 2022-01-24\ 15.57.22.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/myuser/Library/Logs/gym/myapp-mobile.log | xcpretty
[15:57:25]: ▸     The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.
[15:57:25]: ▸ Building Pods/DoubleConversion [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Building Pods/glog [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Aggregate Pods/FBLazyVector [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Aggregate Pods/boost-for-react-native [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Aggregate Pods/RCTRequired [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Building Pods/React-Core-AccessibilityResources [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Processing ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist
[15:57:25]: ▸ Copying /Users/myuser/Documents/myapp/mobile/node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj
[15:57:25]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/myuser/Documents/myapp/mobile/node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj: No such file or directory
[15:57:25]: ▸ Aggregate Pods/React-callinvoker [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ Building Pods/React-jsinspector [Release]
[15:57:25]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[15:57:25]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[15:57:25]: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[15:57:25]: ▸   CpResource /Users/myuser/Documents/myapp/mobile/node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-bcscdkevmsgdkxgqwricfjclvmqw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj
[15:57:25]: ▸ (1 failure)
```

I updated "bundle"'s version and tried to check "Legacy Build" on Xcode but it didn't bring anything.
I'm kinda stuck with this error.

Already tried to remove node_modules and run `npm install`, and nothing changed.
I feel like this file not found has to be built during the npm install command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I kind of fixed it.

What I did was to reinstall **npm** & **nvm** with homebrew, delete the **package-lock.json** and then run `npm install`.
For some reasons, I didn't have any folders named "node_modules" and my package-lock didn't contain any lines with the module "react-native" so I added it back.

Now I'm stuck with something else but I guess I'll have to open a new ticket !